# PHP Passing a Javascript timestamp using json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json, timestamp

I am preparing data to pass to my Javascript in PHP. Encoding that data using json_encode and passing it.

One of the elements I am trying to pass is a javascript timestamp. PHP timestamps are in seconds, Javascript timestamps in milliseconds, so i need to multiply the php timestamp by 1000.

The problem is that the resulting int is too large and gets sent at 1.3239E+12 instead of 1323907200000 losing around 1 day of precision on the way.

One way to do it would be to pass a Date.UTC() function in the json but there's no easy way to do it using json_encode.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$jstimestamp = (string) time() + "000";
```

Try that. I solved a similar problem the same way. However, the easiest is to multiply in the Javascript or divide the js-timestamp with 1000.

Comment: The js library i am using will return an error if a string is passed instead of an int..

Comment: As I commented on another answer here. Look in the source of the library. Find the function where it uses the timestamp and do a workaround like this `var timestamp = parseInt(json.timestamp) * 1000;`

Comment: For reference, I passing the json to the highcharts charting lib. I would need to modify the library to make it work.. not ideal.

Comment: Weird, I solved the exact problem I had with timestamps a while back. It was also highscharts. I simply parsed the numbers as ints in the option-function where I set all the settings.

Comment: Went in and fixed the highcharts script. It worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem in the past by encoding it in as a string, instead of as an integer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the js library i am using trips on the value if it is a string instead of an int

Comment: put parseInt on the variable before it's used?

Answer (score 1):

You can always multiply after receiving (in Javascript), instead of before sending.

Comment: `var timestamp = parseInt(json.timestamp) * 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

use it

$time =  date(strtotime($r->date)) *1000;